# CMD not recognizing Javac

Tags: java, cmd, javac

I've searched for an answer for this on all the threads before and I've not found an answer to my current situation despite those that asked before so here goes.

I cannot get cmd to recognize `javac` at all and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to set the system environment variable `PATH` having just installed the JDK. Here is a literal screen grab of the file path from C: to the JDK bin: [http://imgur.com/a/4cT9m](https://imgur.com/a/4cT9m)

Here is the entirety of the `PATH` system variable (posted here with a line break after each semicolon for easier reading):

```
C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\HP\Digital Imaging\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Digital Imaging\bin\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Digital Imaging\bin\Qt\Qt 4.3.3;
```

As far as I can tell I've edited the path right but nothing works.

Can someone explain to me what I'm not seeing please?

Also I've tried editing the path variable to read `bin\javac`. It still did nothing. I honestly believe I have read all the threads regarding this issue but I am new so if I missed it my bad.

Comment: `C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Java` is not the same as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`. Also, you really should have 64 bit Java anyway.

Comment: Instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` you could also use `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java`. The environment variable with name `ProgramFiles(x86)` has the path to program files folder for x86 applications while the environment variable with name `ProgramFiles` has the path to program files folder for x64 applications (on Windows x64 for 64-bit applications like 64-bit cmd.exe), see Microsoft's TechNet article [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You may reopen the cmd or if it doesn't works restart your machine.

Changes that you make to environment variables do not affect services that run under the Local System account until you restart Windows especially if your OS is not 64 bit.